# How to remove the padding in the first line of span

Tags: html, css

I found this code online, but there is always a padding on the first line in the span. How can I remove that?

Like what is shown in the following image, if I remove the triangle, it will be fine. However, I've tried to set all possible `padding`/`margin` to `0` but there still is a padding at the first line in the span.

[image]

```css
.receiver div:nth-child(1) {
  float: right;
}

.receiver div:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.right_triangle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent gold;
  position: relative;
  right: -16px;
  top: 3px;
}

span {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="receiver">
  <div>
    <img src="test.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="right_triangle"></div>
    <span> longlonglonglong </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not padding but blank space due to word break, next word 'onglong' not place-able that's why it is breaking down. Try to add more width then you will see the effect.

Comment: In case of next time, try using your browser inspector tool to get further details about an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<div class="receiver">
  <div>
    <img src="test.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p class="floattext">
      float text
    </p>
    <div class="right_triangle"></div>
    <span> longlonglonglong </span>
  </div>
</div>

.receiver div:nth-child(1) {
  float: right;
}

.receiver div:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}

.right_triangle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent gold;
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 8px;
}

.floattext {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

span {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: Using `position:relative` would still make the element block level, however `position:absolute` would make it a different layer and so it won't be pushing any other element.

Comment: @AryanTwanju what if I want a fixed text above the right_triangle, how to do that?

Comment: I have edited my answer to incorporate the fixed text that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your CSS with this...

```
<style>
.receiver div:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
}
.right_triangle {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent gold;
  position: relative;
  right: -16px;
  top: 3px;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/964wtww3/

Answer (score 1):

Well first, you use `float` which isn't a good practice and in your case, the reason you see this "padding".
In addition, you gave the `span` `display: block`, so what don't you just use a `div` instead?

Try using `flex` instead of css `float`, change the span to a div and give it width.

Checkout my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mu9ebpc/3/) and code

Answer (score 0):

You have that because of the width constrain you set on the `span` element

```
 span {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

i would suggest you increase the width to `width : 100px`to see the effect of what am saying.

```
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```